# Adding a condition to list comprehension that contain a RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract certain values from logs using RegEx. All the values are then thrown into a list, which will later be used in a Pandas dataframe. So far it has worked well, but the problem is that not all logs contain the values, and if so, I need to add a ' - ' so the dataframe won't break because all arrays must be of equal length.

With the code below, I get the expected output:

```
import re
attribute = "</System><EventData><Data Name='TargetUserName'>superuser</Data><Data Name='TargetDomainName'>ACME</Data>"
username_list = [' - ' if ' '.join(re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute)) not in attribute else ' '.join(re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute))]
print(username_list)
```

Output:

```
['superuser']
```

But if the expression is not found, then I simply get an empty list.

```
attribute = "</System><EventData>superuser</EventData><Data Name='TargetDomainName'>ACME</Data>"
username_list = [' - ' if ' '.join(re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute)) not in attribute else ' '.join(re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute))]
print(username_list)
```

Output

```
['']
```

Expected Output

```
[' - ']
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for helping!

Comment: That looks like XML. If your real data is indeed XML, try using a XML parser instead of regex.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse xml with regex? If your answer is: "Because the xml is in chunks that may not be well-formed" - you could use `html.parser.HTMLParser` which is more forgiving.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Nah, it's json, but my error was really dumb as it was just an extra 'not' in the conditional. It's just like trying to proofread your own essay and find grammar and punctuation mistakes -- almost impossible. But thanks for chiming in!

Comment: `"</System><EventData>superuser</EventData><Data Name='TargetDomainName'>ACME</Data>"` - This is xml. You should parse it with something that parses xml. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about this **definitely** being xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
' - ' if ' '.join(re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute)) not in attribute else ' '.join(re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute))
```

You're checking if the string you found with the regular expression is not in the searched string, but if the regular expression doesn't find anything it returns an empty list. When you join an empty list with ' ', you get an empty string '', which will always match.

Instead you can check if the regular expression found anything, and if not, add ' - '.

Example:

```
import re

attribute = "</System><EventData>superuser</EventData><Data Name='TargetDomainName'>ACME</Data>"
match = re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)", attribute)

username_list = [' - ' if not match else ' '.join(match)]
print(username_list)
```

'match' will be an empty list if the regular expression doesn't find anything. The 'if not match' condition will be true if 'match' is an empty list, and ' - ' will be added to the list. Otherwise, ' '.join(match) will be added.

Answer (score 1):

The issue before was that you were checking if an empty string is in your log entry, which is always true. Now, we check directly if our search pattern finds no match in the log, and if so, we insert ' - ' into the list.

```
attribute = "</System><EventData>superuser</EventData><Data Name='TargetDomainName'>ACME</Data>"
username_list = [' - ' if not re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute) else ' '.join(re.findall("(?<=='TargetUserName'>).*?(?=</Data>)",attribute))]
print(username_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no match, the regex search returns '', which actually *is* in the attribute string. So the first expression evaluates as true and then, denied by "not", turns into false, in which case the else statement takes place, putting '' into the resulting list.